# jest global beforeAll to run once for all tests?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, knex.js

Is it possible for jest config setUp to run a `beforeAll` and `afterAll` **once** for all test files?

I have a database connection that i have set up before the tests are started and when the tests are finished i close the connection, this works for a single test file, but if i have multiple tests files, the connection to the database fails to close, because one of the test file is still using the connection,

so to clarify i want to a globalSetUp a `beforeAll` to run once before all test files, and an `afterAll` that runs once after all tests have finished? so i can have 1 database connection only across the tests?
jest setup in package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/test/setUpTests.ts"]
},
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Jest global Setup and Teardown in a nodeJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138016/how-to-use-jest-global-setup-and-teardown-in-a-nodejs-project)